# ms access 2007 error messages

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-access-2007

Good Day to Everyone!!

Just wanna ask if there is a setting in MS Access 2007 to ignore all error messages, when i ran my application in MS Access 07 there are annoying messages that pop-ups. All I want is to ignore all those message without changing my code.. Thanks

Comment: What kind of messages do you want to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're referring to errors such as this one:

[image: access macro error]

I see this error when accessing an older MS Access application with Access 2007.

I was able to prevent this popup from showing by changing a setting in Access' Trust Center. You can access this by clicking on the Orb, then the "Access Options" button, then "Trust Center" on the left-hand side, and then clicking on the "Trust Center Settings..." button.

[image: trust center window]

In the Trust Center window, click on "Trusted Locations" on the left. In my case, the file I was opening was hosted on a network share, so I had to checkmark "Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended)" before adding the share with the "Add new location" button.

You may also have to make a change in the Macro settings.

Please note, though - these warnings are there for a reason. Changing the settings above could allow malicious code to run on your computer.

[Microsoft suggests the following guidelines](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102564121033.aspx) when deciding if you should trust a specific database:

> - **Your own security policy**  You or your
>     company may have a security policy in
>     place that specifies how to handle
>     Access database files. For example,
>     you might have a very robust backup
>     system in place, and decide that you
>     are willing to trust most database
>     files, unless you have a specific
>     reason not to. Conversely, you may not
>     have a good backup system, and
>     therefore might want to be very
>     cautious when you decide whether to
>     trust a database.
> - **Your goal**  When
>     Access disables content in a database
>     that you have not trusted, it does not
>     block your access to the data in that
>     database. If you want to review the
>     data in a database and do not want to
>     perform any actions that may be
>     unsafe, such as running an action
>     query or using certain macro actions,
>     you do not need to trust the database.
>     If you are not sure whether an action
>     is considered unsafe, you can try to
>     perform the action while the database
>     content has been blocked by disabled
>     mode. If the action is potentially
>     unsafe, it will be blocked in this
>     circumstance.
> - **The database source**  If
>     you created the database, or if you
>     know that it came from a source that
>     you trust, you can decide to trust the
>     database. If the database came from a
>     possibly unreliable source, you might
>     want to leave the database untrusted
>     until you can be sure that its content
>     is safe.
> - **The contents of the database
>     file**  If you cannot make a trust
>     decision based on other information,
>     you might consider thoroughly
>     examining the database contents to see
>     what potentially unsafe content the
>     database might contain. After you
>     conduct a complete check and are sure
>     that the content is safe, you can
>     decide to trust the database.
> - **The security of the location where the
>     database is stored**  Even if you know
>     that the contents of a database file
>     are safe, if the file is stored in a
>     location that is not fully secure, it
>     is possible that someone might
>     introduce unsafe content into the
>     database. You should be careful when
>     deciding to trust database files that
>     are stored in locations that might not
>     be secure.